# Using Classes to define JSON structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

In my project, I have a handful of data model classes that take a response from an API in the constructor.

Here's an example, with an arbitrary `toJSON` method.

```
class Document {
  id: number  
  name: string

  constructor(init: DocumentStructure) {
    this.id = init.id
    this.name = init.name
  }

  toJSON()  {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name
    }
  }
}
```

It's coming into the constructor as an object, so for correct typing I also have a type definition for the object structure that is separate from the class. Assume that it must come in as an object due to requirements further up the chain.

```
type DocumentStructure = {
  id: number
  handle: string
}
```

**My question is**: is there any way to use the class as a structural definition? Could I ever do something like the following, where the incoming `init` object is a JSON structure that matches the attributes of `Document`, but is not actual an instance of the class `Document`?

```
class Document {
  id: number  
  name: string

  constructor(init: Document) {
    this.id = init.id
    this.name = init.name
  }

  toJSON()  {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name
    }
  }
}
```

If this is an impossible/bad idea, what are the TS best practices for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest separating the classes and input structures, e.g. `class Document` and `interface DocumentDTO`:

```js
interface DocumentDTO {
  id: number
  name: string
}

class Document extends DocumentDTO {
  constructor(init: DocumentDTO) {
    this.id = init.id
    this.name = init.name
  }

  toJSON()  {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name
    }
  }
}
```

If though you are in some way restricted, you can also use the following approach:

```js
// A helper type for extractig all non-function properties from type C
type SerializableProperties<C> = {
    [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof C];

// This type will be the same as C but it will not have any function properties
//
// If you don't need the extra generality you can also just say
//
//   type Serializable<C> = Omit<C, 'toJSON'>;
//
// But that might give you some headaches when you start adding methods to those classes :)
type Serializable<C> = Pick<C, SerializableProperties<C>>;

class DocumentClass {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(init: Serializable<DocumentClass>) {
        this.id = init.id
        this.name = init.name
    }

    toJSON(): Serializable<DocumentClass>  {
        return {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name
        }
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEFQCwUwGwA4wE6gC4E8mgGYHtUYAPNZAQwGM0BLAc1DLjlADs8WBaHAVxauvagEyPEmQ0YAZ1wiAtuiwxQAYQBQmbAGUU1RtQBeZAEZwYABRFiJkgDzKAfKAC8oAN6rQn0AG0A0qGoWUABrGAw8HBUAXQAuFT8o0GI0GBYAE2kAMV5+QQB+VhgANxRQON8AblUAX29Q8MjlKKrVEFAAFShqaQ0lAHdqJlAjJTRYUEkyWSUyaWVh7jQApYGhtiWoMhKGFgxcHJpBYVEUa3VFUG1kXTgDY1M7RxczagpguwAaS509QxNzSynahSR72FoUOCzaQAETwFG40xYaGUkMk0ncXgCaTiklIgVoVUxLCmMBxeJYBNUHi8FHYuOQ3CoBAAFIFqGg4lcbnd-jZYfDEcjUZJ7ABKNzUzGeMbdAB01DSzgCLHZ8rSkqlMsksuJ0yVbLQOpJGuqVMxaDwAClNAB5AByzNFnJ+tz+D35CNSQqhjglUq8yBgaG4yCCGP9UoVcS1ao+GojrBJ0a62t1MHjXlNmNN1SAA)TypeScript Playground link here

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with keeping *all* of the class parameters, you can skip the `toJSON` method and use the built-in

```js
// { id: 'foo', name: 'bar' }
JSON.stringify(new Document(...))
```

Comment: Sure, the toJSON is just an arbitrary method on the class for example's sake. What I'm wondering is if I can use the class as a type for a plain object that has all the same attributes but none of the methods.